# Primefaces CSS and corporate CSS, how to avoid conflicts?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I required to include a corporate css in all web applications. The problem that it's conflicting with Primefaces css rules and some elements are becoming destroyed. For example, autocomplete, tabView, etc... 
I tried to add manually Primefaces css files at the bottom of head (last has higher precedence) but unsuccessfully. When I replaced in primefaces.css  ";" -> " !important;" it began to be a little better but not sufficient. Is there a simple way to override css rules of corporate style with rules from css? Actually I don't use corporate classes at all except header and footer. Now I have to repair it manually or use iframe.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would it help if you put your own styles inside <f:facet name="first"> in h:head? Then I guess they should be overridden by primefaces later

Comment: Just tried but it didn't work((( Possible it's inline element styles and they have higher precedence.

Comment: I worry that there isn't another way except manually look for conflicting rules and eliminate them, the problem that corporate css is huge, very huge and complex css file (((

Comment: In firebug you can go to css mode and disable the styles one by one. I think that might be handy

Comment: Thank you, it looks promising, will try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)